# Managed property to an Object in a list from a bean

Tags: xpages, jsf-1.2

I would do something with a Managed Bean but I dont' find a solution
To explain what I will do I will show a small example:

I have created a Object Data with the following structure

```
public class  Data implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5156829783321214340L;
    String value="";

    public Data() {
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(String data) {
        this. value = data;
    }
}
```

As you can see ist a simple dataholder with one property
now I created a secound Object whitch will be my bean it only holds a list of Data Objects

```
public class Databean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9205700558419738494L;

    private ArrayList<Data> datalist; 

    public Databean()
    {
        datalist = new ArrayList<Data>();
        Data newItem;
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            newItem = new Data();
            datalist.add(newItem);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getDatalist() {
        return datalist;
    }

    public void setDatalist(ArrayList<Data> datalist) {
        this.datalist = datalist;
    }

}
```

The Declaration in the Faces-config to publish the bean is no Problem

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>managedBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>de.itwu.Databean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

So now to my problem:
I would like to create a Managed Property or something else to make a connection to an inputtext

in a repreat control e.g:

```
<xp:repeat value="#{managedBean.datalist}" var="rowData">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" defaultValue="#{rowData.value}"></xp:inputText>
</xp:repeat>
```

does anyone have an Idea how this could work?

So exmaple corrected but it doesen't work the Ich ich set Datualt values in the Data-Object they are shown. But when I edit the values in the Inputtextfields they are not automatically written back to the Object. I Thing the Problem is the Daclaration in the Faces-Config. Ideas?

Comment: @per-henrik-lausten has a nice tutorial on his blog. http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable assigned in the repeat to var (rowData) will contain an instance of your Data class. To bind each input control to the value field you refer to that property. Because you have a getValue() and setValue() defined a value binding will be created and you will be able to edit the content. If only a getValue() method is defined a method binding is created and the field will not be editable.

```
<xp:repeat value="#{managedBean.datalist}" var="rowData">
  <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{rowData.value}"></xp:inputText>
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: So I corrected the Databinding in the Inputtext. But when I Change a Value in the Field at the Page it is not written back to the Data-Object automatically. Could it be that the faces-Config need some more text like managed propert text or so?

Comment: Ok now all works fine after clearing the cache of the domino server

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is wrong.

```
<xp:repeat value="#{managedBean.datalist}" var="rowData">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" defaultValue="#{rowData.value}"></xp:inputText>
</xp:repeat>
```

`rowData` contains Data object, which populates getter/setter for field `value`, not `datavalue`.